# formset is valid but returns empty cleaned_data field

Tags: django, django-forms, cleaned-data

I have a formset that returns empty cleaned_data, even though the formset is valid.
my view is like this:

```
def edit_files(request):
    file_formSet = formset_factory(FileUploadForm)
    if request.POST:
        formset = file_formSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                form_data = form.cleaned_data
                if form_data:
                    up_file = upload_file(form_data['file'])
    else:
        formset = file_formSet()

    return render_to_response('edit_files.html', {'formset': formset})
```

it is an upload form and with this problem I can't save files
upload_file is one of my implemented methods and it works fine, I have tested this.

Comment: Can you post your code of `FileUploadForm` and does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: yes rohan, form is posting and encryption is alright, but the problem is html request returns no file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,
i just wanna complete the topic
so if anyone has the same problem, he/she can use this page to solve it
main keys to this solution are:
1- never forget the encryption type
2- use separate forms for different functionality

so in the template i should use:

```
<form method="POST" action="." encrypt="multipart/form-data">
```

and use two separate forms for add and delete files
like this:
this one for adding files:

```
<form method="POST" action="." encrypt="multipart/form-data" id="add_file">
```

and this one for deleting files:

```
<form method="POST" action="." encrypt="multipart/form-data" id="delete_file">
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message when I forgot to append the parenthesis () after `is_valid`. `Formset.is_valid` returned `True`, but there was no cleaned data simply because the `is_valid()` function was not called to return the cleaned data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the following line;

```
... snip ... 

for form in formset.forms:
    form_data = form.cleaned_data

... snip ...
```

You appear to be missing the `.forms` part from the formset.

Comment: tnx for answering, but it doesn't work too, the problem is there is no cleaned_data, and i think it's related to the post request, but i don't know what's wrong :-??

Answer (score 0):

ok
i found out after using some break points, that it's actually request's fault, request.FILES is empty

Answer (score 0):

tnx for all of your answers, i'v solved the problem, 
i had one form with two functionality: add_file and del_file
after i separated them, every thing was ok
but there is a problem in the looking of the page
after i add some files, like 3 file and then request.POST sent and i return to the page again
i actually see three row of file input, instead of one
it really reduce the beauty 
any advice?